# Why is wxGridSizer much slower to initialize on a wxDialog then on a wxFrame?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

It seems that this is specific to windows, here is an example that reproduces the effect:

```
import wx


def makegrid(window):
    grid = wx.GridSizer(24, 10, 1, 1)
    window.SetSizer(grid)
    for i in xrange(240):
        cell = wx.Panel(window)
        cell.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(i, i, i))
        grid.Add(cell, flag=wx.EXPAND)


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        makegrid(self)


class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)
        makegrid(self)


class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        btn1 = wx.Button(self, label="Show Frame")
        btn2 = wx.Button(self, label="Show Dialog")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Add(btn1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(btn2, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnShowFrame)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnShowDialog)

    def OnShowFrame(self, event):
        TestFrame(self).Show()

    def OnShowDialog(self, event):
        TestDialog(self).ShowModal()


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = Test()
app.TopWindow.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I have tried this on the following configurations:

- Windows 7 with Python 2.5.4 and wxPython 2.8.10.1
- Windows XP with Python 2.5.2 and wxPython 2.8.7.1
- Windows XP with Python 2.6.0 and wxPython 2.8.9.1
- Ubuntu 9.04 with Python 2.6.2 and wxPython 2.8.9.1

The wxDialog wasn't slow only on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a reply on the [wxPython-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/wxPython-users/browse_thread/thread/66762899a9f3b697#), the problem can be fixed by calling `Layout` explicitly before the dialog is shown.

> This is really weird...
>
> My guess is that this is due to
>   Windows and wxWidgets not dealing very
>   well with overlapping siblings, and so
>   when the sizer is doing the initial
>   layout and moving all the panels from
>   (0,0) to where they need to be that
>   something about the dialog is causing
>   all of them to be refreshed and
>   repainted at each move.  If you
>   instead do the initial layout before
>   the dialog is shown then it is just as
>   fast as the frame.
>
> You can do this by adding a call to window.Layout() at the end of
>   makegrid.
>
> --  Robin Dunn